# How to make alignment in css?

Tags: html, css

What is the type of alignment of text on the image?

The result I need:

[image]

I tried to apply `text-align: center;` and `text-align: left;`, but effect was different.

My 2 results:

[image]

Comment: Avoid justify alignment on the web - https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24025/should-text-on-the-web-be-justified

Comment: adding a js fiddle helps more to get a better answer

Comment: What is  js fiddle ? can you give an example how to get such result?

Comment: You can also use codepen or a snippet here codepen example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aWvLzN (snippet can be generated straight into question/answer)

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: justify;` Is the alignment. Plus, note that the font size and weight is different.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `text-align` + `text-align-last`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align-last/

```css
p {
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:center;
}
/* makup*/
p {
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:1em;
  border:solid black;
  background:gray;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

See also http://caniuse.com/#search=text-align-last

Answer (score 0):

GCyrillus solution is the right one, however note that it is not supported on Safari, so I'd like to suggest a little hack which may suit you best if you wish to have multi-browser support.

- Wrap last line on a `<span>` tag
- Inspect it's `width` (in example is `260px`) and subtract it by the `p`'s width - suppose it's `300px` (`300px - 260px = 40px`)
- Give sides `padding` to the `span` to center (`20px` each side)

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic impedit reprehenderit voluptates, voluptatibus ut explicabo, repudiandae, reiciendis soluta <span>facere in cum eveniet architecto sint.</span></p>
```